# jQuery Validate - how to prevent the plugin from validating onblur events for a specific feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker, jquery-validate

Is there anyway to stops jQuery validate from validating the form when a blur event occurs?

I have three pairs of start/end dates and each one of these six fields uses DatePicker plus each pair of dates validate if the other field of the pair is filled because the form can't be submitted if the end date is filled but the start date isn't and vice-versa.

The problem occurs when the user picks a date from DatePicker, the browser fires the blur event and jQuery validate tries to validate the form and realizes that the other field of the pair is empty and then displays the error message. Besides when user fills the second field of the pair, again the blur event is fired before the field is filled and the validation plugin displays the error message.

**The HTML:**

```
<form>
    <table width="95%" id="tabela_interna">
        <thead><tr valign="middle"><th colspan="6">Report</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td width="14%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialSolicitacao">Data de Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialSolicitacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="12%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalSolicitacao">Data de Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalSolicitacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td width="14%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialLiberacao">Data de Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialLiberacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialLiberacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="12%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalLiberacao">Data de Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalLiberacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalLiberacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td width="14%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialInternacao">Data de Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialInternacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialInternacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="12%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalInternacao">Data de Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalInternacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalInternacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**The jQuery plugin we've written:**

```
$.fn.aplicaLayoutPersonalizavel = function() {
    personalizaAplicacao();
    return this;
};

function personalizaAplicacao() {
    $(".data").apagaDataInvalida().mask("99/99/9999").numeric().datepicker().attr("maxlength", 10);
}

$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorContainer : "#msgErros ul",
    errorLabelContainer: "#msgErros",
    wrapper: "li",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var erros = $("div#msgErros");
        if (typeof $("#acao").val() === "undefined") {
            if (erros.length > 1) {
                erros.empty();
            }
            stopAnimating();
            erros.html("<ul><li>O parâmetro ação deve ser definido.</li></ul>");
            erros.show();
            return false;
        }

        $.blockUI();
        var dadosRelatorio = $(form).formSerialize();
        switch (parseInt($("#acao").val())) {
            case 1:
                if (typeof urlRelatorio !== 'undefined' && urlRelatorio != null) {
                    $("#respostaRelatorio").jqGrid("GridUnload");
                    $("#respostaRelatorio").jqGrid({
                        url: urlRelatorio + "?" + dadosRelatorio,
                        colModel: modeloColunas,
                        autowidth: typeof larguraAutomatizada !== "undefined" && larguraAutomatizada != null ? larguraAutomatizada : false
                    });
                } else {
                    form.submit();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                downloadArquivo(urlExportarExcel, dadosRelatorio);
                break;
            case 3:
                downloadArquivo(urlExportarPdf, dadosRelatorio);
                break;
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function() { stopAnimating(); }
});

$.fn.inicializaValidacaoFormulario = function() {
    $("form").validate({
        rules: typeof regras !== "undefined" && regras != null ? regras : {},
        messages: typeof mensagens !== "undefined" && mensagens != null ? mensagens : {},
        agrupamentos: typeof agrupamentos !== "undefined" && agrupamentos != null ? agrupamentos : {}
    });
    return this;
};
```

**The validation:**

```
regras = {
    "filtro.codigoProcedimento": { range: [1, 9223372036854775807] },
    "filtro.codigoHospital": { range: [1, 9223372036854775807] },
    "filtro.codigoSegurado": { range: [1, 9223372036854775807] },
    "filtro.numeroSolicitacao": { range: [1, 2147483647] },
    "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataFinalSolicitacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataFinalSolicitacao", 90] },
    "filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataInicialSolicitacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataInicialSolicitacao", 90] },
    "filtro.dataInicialInternacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataFinalInternacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataFinalInternacao", 90] },
    "filtro.dataFinalInternacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataInicialInternacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataInicialInternacao", 90] },
    "filtro.dataInicialLiberacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataFinalLiberacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataFinalLiberacao", 90] },
    "filtro.dataFinalLiberacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataInicialLiberacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataInicialLiberacao", 90] }
};

mensagens = {
    "filtro.codigoProcedimento": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 9223372036854775807 ao preencher o cartão." },
    "filtro.codigoHospital": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 9223372036854775807 ao preencher o estipulante." },
    "filtro.codigoSegurado": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 9223372036854775807 ao preencher a solicitação." },
    "filtro.numeroSolicitacao": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 2147483647 ao preencher o referenciado." }
};

agrupamentos = {
    datasSolicitacao: "#dataInicialSolicitacao #dataFinalSolicitacao",
    datasLiberacao: "#dataInicialLiberacao #dataFinalLiberacao",
    datasInternacao: "#dataInicialInternacao #dataFinalInternacao"
};

$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    require_from_group: $.format("Por favor, preencha ao menos {0} uma das duplas de datas para realizar a consulta.")
});
```

I don't want the plugin to stops validating the other forms when a blur event occurs, just this one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is to override the onfocusout property of the jQuery Validate plugin. So I did as above:

**Changes in the jQuery plugin:**

```
$.fn.inicializaValidacaoFormulario = function() {
    $("form").validate({
        rules: typeof regras !== "undefined" && regras != null ? regras : {},
        messages: typeof mensagens !== "undefined" && mensagens != null ? mensagens : {},
        agrupamentos: typeof agrupamentos !== "undefined" && agrupamentos != null ? agrupamentos : {},
        onfocusout: typeof preventBlurEvents !== "undefined" && preventBlurEvents != null ? preventBlurEvents : {}
    });
    return this;
};
```

**And I added this to the validation:**

```
preventBlurEvents = function (element, event) {
    if (!$(element).attr("class").contains("data")) {
        $.validator.defaults.onfocusout.call(this, element, event);
    }
};
```